# Share database using Mysql with web app and c# windows application

Tags: c#, html, mysql, visual-studio

I have a web app and a c# windows application, the web app is in another PC and I want them to share with the same database using MySql. What to do?

Comment: Start the MySQL server and let both of them connect.  Whether this is a good idea or not is another question.  I think a REST data service, shared by both would be a better idea.  But your way isn't difficult.

Comment: Are you just asking how to use a MySQL database in your applications?  There are examples and tutorials for that.  What have you tried?

Comment: I know how to use MySql, it's just that this is the first time I'm doing this kind of thing and I wonder if it's just possible, and if so, what to do?

Comment: @Ekko - have you ever connected an application to a DB? Just do that for both the windows application and the web application. Plenty of tutorials about connecting a .NET app (mvc or w/e) to a DB.

Comment: @Ekko: If what's possible?  Using a MySQL database in any given application?  Yes, that's possible.  "What to do" I guess would be to find some examples and tutorials on how to connect to MySQL from .NET and implement that in your applications.  It's not really clear where or why you're stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web application needs the credentials for the MySQL database to point to the IP address of the MySQL server.

The C# app will most likely say to connect to localhost (IP address of 127.0.0.1).

To find the IP address of the machine type 'ipconfig' into a windows command prompt or "ifconfig" into a terminal varying on the OS of your MySQL server machine.

This IP address needs to be placed into the connection settings of the web app so it can find the MySQL database.